# How to search for "%" in sql table-column

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

I have a table with a column "Remarks"...How to search "%" in this column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this

```
where Remarks like'%[%]%'
```

you need to put brackets around it, more info here [LIKE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE CHARINDEX('%', Remarks) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 ways, you could use

```
where Remarks like '%[%]%'
```

or

```
where Remarks like '%!%%' escape '!'
```