# c# sql search with LIKE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-like

I have a database of gigs that I'm searching by Artist and trying to use LIKE in the sql query but failing.

I have tried:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TB_CA_gigs WHERE Artist LIKE '[%" + Artist + "%]'";
```

which brings back no records

```
string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TB_CA_gigs WHERE Artist LIKE '%[" + Artist + "]%'";
```

which brings back all records

```
string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TB_CA_gigs WHERE Artist LIKE '" + Artist + "'";
```

which brings back no records

I have tried using CONTAINS in various ways but always get the same error:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONTAINS'.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
>      at WebService1.Service1.Search(String Artist) in C:\Users\strscac\Desktop\VS\WebService1\WebService1\WebService1\Service1.asmx.cs:line 36

Comment: why are you using brackets [] in your like? Try just doing like '%" + Artist + "%'

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like you are using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed one combination that will work:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TB_CA_gigs WHERE Artist LIKE '%" + Artist + "%'";
```

And as wahwahwah said, as I'm sure others will too: as a good practice, learn and use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

For a simple example of a parameterized query, check out the MSDN documentation for [`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

Comment: that worked thanks, just to answer your question - I was using the brackets as I saw it on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231744/how-to-search-for-in-sql-table-column

Comment: @user3606041 In that example, the `[]` are used as "escape characters" to signify that the query is looking for result containing `%` - such as if you had `5%` as a value in your database.

Comment: @user3606041 please also read the link Cory posted. You should never use the statement here in production.

Comment: @user3606041 The correct parameterized version of your query would be  `"SELECT * FROM TB_CA_gigs WHERE Artist LIKE '%' + @Artist + '%'"` and then you would add a parameter called `@Artist`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
string strSQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM TB_CA_gigs WHERE Artist LIKE '%{0}%'", Artist);
```

Though you should always parameterize your values (e.g. `Artist` should be a param) to protect from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: ummm... that's not what it means to create a parameterized query. What if `Artist` was = `DROP TABLE Artist`? Your example is no different than the one the OP uses... [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)

Comment: Yes... and that is why I said "though you should" not "this is an example of".  If the OP had asked how to create parameterized queries I would have pointed them in the right direction.  As it is, I was including it as a note on a best practice (well, more like a minimum accepted practice).

Comment: That was not at all clear (and really not terribly clear now) from your pre-edit posts... but the condescension is definitely of value :)